# How to append a $ sign to a float value in a field that is both width-specified and right-justified?

Tags: java, formatting

I need to append a $ sign to float values that go in a field that is both width-specified AND right justified.

It's easy enough to use system.out.printf("$%8.2f", r.getPrice()), but that gives me a $ sign that is left justified while my float values are right justified, e.g., $   23.99 (with the unused width-specified spaces BETWEEN the $ sign and float value) instead of    $23.99 (with the unused width-specified spaces to the left of BOTH both the float value AND the $ sign).

Note that the value being assigned to the field comes from a class 'getter' (don't know if that makes a difference).

Here's the code:

```
list.stream()
    .forEach(r -> 
    System.out.printf("%4d %-15s %-27s %6d %8.2f\n", r.getId(),    
    r.getDepartment(), r.getDescription(), r.getQuantity(), r.getPrice())
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a locale-sensitive idiom that works well:

Use [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()):

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

// Get a currency format for the current locale.
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(fmt.format(120.00)); //replace here your variable
```

If your current locale is in the US, the `println` will print **$120.00**

Another example:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
System.out.println(fmt.format(120.00));
```

This will print: £120.00

Comment: This information, while interesting, does not answer the question.  Notice that the code provided is a stream with a lambda that does an iteration, and the formatting must be applied to each value in the resulting list in a way that doesn't dimply append the symbol in a left-justified column parallel to the right-justified, width-defined column.

Comment: I don't understand what do you refer. Please try to explain to me, so I can help you.